# adding new feature to confirm box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
<%= button_to "Acknowledge", ack_something_path, :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?" %>
```

i want to also display in the confirm box

```
%br
%input{:name => "option1", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Milk"}
Milk                   
%br                   
%input{:name => "option2", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Butter"}                 
Butter                  
%br                   
%input{:name => "option3", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Cheese"}                    
Cheese                      
%br
```

bu i don't know how to put it

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation alerts don't display HTML very well and are generally only used for quick Yes/No questions or generic alerts. If you want a more robust messaging dialogs, look into Jquery UI Dialogs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: can i use Haml with Jquery UI?